# Xtext autocompletion - Add description?

Tags: autocomplete, grammar, xtext

For example, I have the following expression in one of my Xtext-rules:

```
('COUNTER' COUNTER=("On"|"Tw"|"Th"))?
```

If I then use autocompletion in my editor, it looks like the following:

[image]

But I want to add some extra information in terms of an description, which should look (approximately) like this:

[image]

Is there a way to implement such a feachure in Xtext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to override `AbstractContentProposalProvider.getKeywordDisplayString(Keyword)` in your `MyDslProposalProvider`.